# Get all Members from Domain Local Group across multi-forest environment

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have a domain local group that is a part of domain A in forest A.

I am trying to iterate all the members in this group. It iterates through all the domains of forest A just fine, but does not iterate any members of the group that are in domain b, in forest B.

Is the only approach to iterate through the same code starting in different forests?

We have tried using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` classes, but there appears to be an issue with them and Windows Server 2012 domain controllers.

```
private List<User> getUsersInGroup(string groupDN)
    {
        var users = new List<User>();

        using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("GC://rootDSE"))
        {
            var rootName = de.Properties["rootDomainNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
            using (var userBinding = new DirectoryEntry("GC://" + rootName))
            {
                using (DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(userBinding))
                {
                    adSearch.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
                    adSearch.Filter = String.Format("(&(memberOf={0})(objectClass=person))", groupDN);
                    adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
                    adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname");
                    adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
                    adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
                    adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("title");
                    adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
                    adSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");

                    using (var searchResults = adSearch.FindAll())
                    {
                        foreach (SearchResult result in searchResults)
                        {
                            User u = new User();

                            u.UserName = result.Properties["samaccountname"][0].ToString();
                            u.DistinguishedName = result.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
                            if (result.Properties.Contains("title"))
                            {
                                u.Title = result.Properties["title"][0].ToString();
                            }

                            if (result.Properties.Contains("department"))
                            {
                                u.Department = result.Properties["department"][0].ToString();
                            }

                            if (result.Properties.Contains("displayName"))
                            {
                                u.DisplayName = result.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();
                            }
                            u.DomainName = getDomainFromDN(u.DistinguishedName);


                            users.Add(u);
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }


        return users;
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Two points of clarification: (1) You said: "Is the only approach to iterate through the same code starting in different forests?" - does that mean that approach works for you?  If it does, what do you not like about that approach? (2) You said "We have tried using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` classes, but there appears to be an issue with them and Windows Server 2012 domain controllers."  What was the issue you encountered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to search for group members in a different forest by using the **memberOf** property because it's just not set when you add a user to a domain local group that belongs to another forest.

Instead, AD creates an object of type **ForeignSecurityPrincipal** in the domain of the group that has the target user's SID as its **CN**. Then the **DN** of that object gets added to the group's **members** property.

Unfortunately, unlike **user** objects, **foreingSecurityPrincipal** objects never get **memberOf** property, so your search won't find them even if you remove **objectType** condition.

So, you really should reverse your search and enumerate the group's **members** property as suggested by rufanov.

But you should also extend the code to handle those foreign security principals. To detect if your **DirectoryEntry** represents foreign principal you can check if its object class contains *foreignSecurityPricipal*. If it does, the **CN** property would contain the SID which you can use to search by **objectSid** property

```
if (de.Properties["objectClass"].Contains("foreignSecurityPrincipal"))
{
    // use this value in a search condition for objectSid
    var sidString = de.Properties["cn"].Cast<string>().First();

    IdentityReference id = new SecurityIdentifier(sid);

    var account = id.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString().Split('\\');

    var userName = account[1];
    var domainName = account[0];
}
```

Comment: that was what i was missing - along with using *members* and not *memberOf* - thank you for your help! updated your post to show how to extract the domain and login from the sid.

Answer (score 2):

Why you can't just enumerate members of target group, instead of searching whole forest for users that has target group as one of "memberof" property values? It's can be much faster/simpler way than using DirectorySearcher for this task. Group "member" property are forest-wide, so it will include members from any domain in forest.

Code for getting user's collection may look like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Linq;

namespace AdTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = new Program();
            var users = p.GetMembersOf("LDAP://CN=SQL Adminsistrators,OU=_System accounts and groups,OU=Domain Users,DC=test,DC=net");
            // do something with users
        }

        private List<User> GetMembersOf(string groupdn)
        {
            var context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Forest);
            var Result = new List<User>();
            var GroupEntity = new DirectoryEntry(groupdn);
            var Members = (IEnumerable)GroupEntity.Invoke("Members", null);

            foreach (var member in Members)
            {
                var UserEntry = new DirectoryEntry(member);
                var User = GetUser(UserEntry);

                if(User != null)
                    Result.Add(User);
            }


            return Result;

        }

        private User GetUser(DirectoryEntry UserEntry)
        {
            var Result = new User();

            foreach (PropertyValueCollection UserProperty in UserEntry.Properties)
            {
                switch (UserProperty.PropertyName)
                {
                    case "sAMAccountName":
                        Result.UserName = (string)UserProperty.Value;
                        break;
                    case "distinguishedName":
                        Result.DistinguishedName = (string)UserProperty.Value;
                        Result.DomainName = getDomainFromDN((string)UserProperty.Value);
                        break;
                    case "title":
                        Result.Title = (string)UserProperty.Value;
                        break;
                    case "department":
                        Result.Department = (string)UserProperty.Value;
                        break;
                    case "displayName":
                        Result.DisplayName = (string)UserProperty.Value;
                        break;
                    case "objectClass":
                        var UserClasses = (object[])UserProperty.Value;

                        if (UserClasses.Contains("user"))
                            break;
                        else
                            return null;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return Result;
        }

        private string getDomainFromDN(string p)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        public string groupDN { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an "Unspecified Error" when using this code, because the `DirectoryEntry GroupEntity` is not bound to any directory service (The `context`  variable is not referenced at all)

Comment: Actually, **DirectorySearcher** is much faster than getting instances of **DirectoryEntry** because when you specify which properties you want to get the searcher will make sure that you're only getting those properties. **DirectoryEntry** on the other hand, fetches all properties and that takes quite a while. I actually had to rewrite our code from using **DirectoryEntry** to **DirectorySearcher/SearchResult** in order to improve performance.