# Using two different domains for validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, security

I am currently working on a validation step for a new project. All the code is working except for this part (as described below). I am trying to check is a user (domain1) is in a group of domain2. Everything I am trying is returning a null for the user, and I am not sure why.

Here is the function that I am using.

```
public void runTask(string serverName, string taskName)
        {
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, loginWindow.getUsername());
            GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, ADGroup);


            if (user.IsMemberOf(group))
            {
                using (TaskService tasksrv = new TaskService(serverName, loginWindow.getUsername(), domain, loginWindow.getPassword()))
                {
                    Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Task task = tasksrv.FindTask(taskName);
                    if (!task.IsActive)
                    {
                        if (task.Enabled == true)
                        {
                            //task.Run();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            log.LogMessage("Task was disabled. Enabling...");
                            task.Enabled = true;
                            //task.Run();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // send email
                        string body = "User: " + loginWindow.getUsername().ToUpper() + "<br/><br/>" + "Server: " + serverName + "<br/><br/>" + task.Name + " is already running.";

                        // send email confirmation
                        email = new Email(false);
                        email.SendMail(toEmail, fromEmail, serverName + subject, body);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When I set domain = where the username exists it returns a value but does not find the ADGroup. When I switch it to the domain of the ADGroup, the user is null.

loginWindow is a simple class that validates the users credentials. Task is the windows task that I am trying to run.

Any thoughts or tips would be helpful because right now I am at a loss.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from the code it looks like you're using the same domain-scoped **PrincipalContext** object to look up both the user and the group and since they are actually in different domains then at least each lookup should be performed using its own context:

```
        PrincipalContext userCtx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain1);
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(userCtx, loginWindow.getUsername());

        PrincipalContext groupCtx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain2);
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(groupCtx, ADGroup);
```

This should give you non-null results for both **user** and **group**. I'm not sure, though, if `user.IsMemberOf(group)` would work. Active Directory uses **foreignSecurityPrincipal** records to keep records of cross-domain group membership and it's only using the **members** attribute of the group for that. The user record does not get a matching **memberOf** record. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669922/get-all-members-from-domain-local-group-across-multi-forest-environment/23090208#23090208) for details.

Comment: Perfect! I actually did try this, however I must have mistyped something because it is now working (in terms of giving non-nulls). How do you think I should go about validating that the user is a member of the group if the memberOf doesnt work?

Comment: I would just try `IsMemberOf` first, just like in your code. If not that, I would try to check `GroupPrincipal.Members`, or even `GroupPrincipal.GetMembers(true)` for recursive search. If none of that works, there is a link in the "here" word of the last sentence of my answer.